# return string of previous row with measure in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

hello everyone i have the table [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKbM4.png)

i added it to my visual pane as a table and result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmgQW.png)

i know how to do it in calculated column but i want to make a measure that will return same result as the calculated column

[Calculated Column Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9meWn.png)

i treid

`Previous Month State =  CALCULATE(MAX('Amos Table'[State Name]),'Amos Table'[Month ID] < MAX('Amos Table'[Month ID]))`

`Previous Month State =  CALCULATE(MAX('Amos Table'[State Name]),'Amos Table'[Month ID] = MAX('Amos Table'[Month ID]) - 1 )`

but no avail

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
=
VAR ThisMonthID =
    MIN ( 'Amos Table'[Month ID] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Amos Table'[State Name] ),
        'Amos Table'[Month ID] = ThisMonthID - 1
    )
```

Comment: it didnt work it still shows blank

Comment: Well, obviously it has to be included in a visual alongside the *Month ID* field. Otherwise, what would you expect it to show? You should amend your original post to include copiable data, not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
Measure 2 = 
VAR ThisMonthID =
    MAX ( 'Table (2)'[Month ID] )
VAR result =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table (2)'[Status] ),REMOVEFILTERS('Table (2)'[Month-Year],'Table (2)'[Status]),
        'Table (2)'[Month ID] = ThisMonthID - 1
    )
RETURN
IF(ISBLANK(result),"",result)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).